# Force dock name on Fedora with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, fedora

I have a Java Swing application running on several OS.

On Fedora, when I start the application the Java main class is displayed with dashes as a menu next to the Applications and Places menu.

How can I force this name to be my application name and not the Java class with the full package before?

On Mac OS I can use the `-Xdock:name=` command line argument to force the name. Is there an equivalent on Fedora?